# .net WCF GET HTTPS 400 Bad Request but works fine with Http

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl, https

I have a WCF on a windows Server 2008 R2. I have a SSL certificate.

With IE, the http URL working fine (I get my data) but with Https I have a 400 Bad Request.

below the web.config for my wcf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>    
  </basicHttpBinding>      
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior name="ServiceRequestResourcesAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />      
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="ServiceRequestResourcesAspNetAjaxBehaviorHttps">          
    </behavior>

  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceRequestResourcesBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />          
    </behavior>        
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceRequestResourcesBehaviors" 
           name="BaseSite.ServiceRequestResources">

   <endpoint address="" 
             behaviorConfiguration="ServiceRequestResourcesAspNetAjaxBehaviorHttps" 
             binding="basicHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
             contract="BaseSite.ServiceRequestResources" />

    <endpoint address="" 
              behaviorConfiguration="ServiceRequestResourcesAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BaseSite.ServiceRequestResources" />

  </service>      
</services>
```

Comment: Trying adding SvcTraceViewer logging to your config to get more details about the error.

Comment: Any kind of certificate warning will result in an error 400, when using WCF.  When you go to the URL directly, are you getting any warnings?

Comment: with SvcTraceViewer I catch the error : "System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty"

Comment: Any warning when I go directly to the URL....

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of test, it's working. I need to configure the bindings section in `webHttpBinding` rather than `basicHttpBinding`, but I don't know why.

Below my bindings section:

```
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your  section, have you tried adding an endpoint for HTTPS, like this:

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceRequestResourcesBehaviors" 
        name="BaseSite.ServiceRequestResources">

        <endpoint address="" 
          behaviorConfiguration="ServiceRequestResourcesAspNetAjaxBehaviorHttps" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          contract="BaseSite.ServiceRequestResources" />

        <endpoint address="" 
          behaviorConfiguration="ServiceRequestResourcesAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BaseSite.ServiceRequestResources" />

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>      
</services>
```